# Tangent to a circle equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, circles, tangent-line, desmos

[image: Via desmos]

So I wanted to make a program in desmos which shows a tangent to a circle of user defined radius r at the point q (y co ordinate). I've achieved this so far but of course due to negative square roots, etc. I can only have the tangent line be shown in the first quadrant. It dissapears in quadrant two and three, and doesn't work in quadrant four. Can someone please make corrections.

Answer (score 3):

Let the circle be given by

$ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $

A point $(p, q)$ on the circle is parameterized by the angle $\theta$ as follows

$ (p, q) = r (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta) ) $

The tangent at $(p, q)$ has a unit normal vector equal to $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta) )$

Therefore, the equation you want to plot is

$ \cos(\theta) ( x - p) + \sin(\theta)( y - q ) = 0 $

This is shown below for $r = 2.7$ and $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3} $

[image]

Comment: +1. You might want to delete  the previous answer.

Comment: Wow you're smart and committed. Thank you very much

Comment: No., it is too late for that, I've already written it, and , moreover, it contains, I believe, important information that can benefit others.

Comment: @WhyHosamWhy can you please explain the unit vector part please

Comment: The tangent line is perpendicular to the the radius which extends from the origin to $ r (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta) ) $, thus it is perpendicular to the unit vector $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$.  This is a unit vector because $\cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 = 1$.  Now if a line if perpendicular to a vector $(a, b)$, and passes through the point $(x_1, y_1)$ then its equation is $ a (x - x_1) + b (y - y_1) = 0 $

Comment: Thanks @WhyHosamWhy

Comment: My pleasure; glad I could help.